# Mouseover even in javascript wont output

Tags: javascript, events, mouseover

Oh the splash screen of my new site I wish to have a mouseover event which will change the colour of my logo every time the mouse is moved. Below I have listed the code I have so far, but I cannot get it to display my image.

```
var images = new Array()
images[0] = 'img/CMbl.png'
images[1] = 'img/CMo.png'
images[2] = 'img/CMg.png'
images[3] = 'img/CMp.png'
images[4] = 'img/CMblu.png'

var p = images.length;

logo = document.getElementById( 'logo' ),
console = document.getElementById( 'console' );


logo.addEventListener('mousemove', changeImage);


function changeImage() {

var rand = Math.round(Math.random()*(p-1));

var image = p[ rand ];

if ( image == logo.src ) {

    changeImage();
    return false;
}


logo.src = console.innerText = image;
    function showImage(){
        document.write('<img src="+image[rand]">');
    }
}
```

and my output in html should be (Inside the class 'logo')

```
<script language="javascript">
showImage()
</script>
```

I cannot see why it's not working. I am using a similar code to change image on refresh, which still uses math.random() and an array to call the images.

Comment: var image = p[ rand ]; what is that for ? shouldn't it be images[rand]

Comment: In additional what harsha has said, the `document.write()` line should be `document.write('<img src="' + image[rand]+ '">');`. Probably `document.write()` also wipes all the code from the page, but can't say that for sure, since there's not all the code... Addition to these, `console` is a native function / object, it's better to use some other variable name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the way this should look:

```
document.write('<img src="' + image[rand] + '">');
```

(your script is full of mistakes from what I can see. I'll make a quick, working one for you as an example.)

Here is a working example(I think this is what you're going for) [Jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/zachrip/z3fUQ/2)
As you can see, it comes out to a terrible looking effect, I wouldn't suggest using it.

Comment: hey, I'm not sure if it's too late but I cannot make it work once I implement it. Excuse how ugly it currently looks: http://cmiddleton.net/hello/ if you could point me in the right direction that'd be awesome.

Comment: @CharlieMiddleton Try putting the script in the body tag, also, just copy my code exactly, don't modify it except for putting in your images.

Answer (score 0):

I've made a JSfiddle which cleans up some of the code, and makes use of jQuery.

http://jsfiddle.net/jackcannon/2EXs5/

```
var images = [
        'http://colorvisiontesting.com/plate%20with%205.jpg',
        'http://regentsparkcollege.org.uk/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/test.jpg',
        'http://nyquil.org/uploads/IndianHeadTestPattern16x9.png',
        'http://25.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m9p3n1vJmZ1rexr16o1_400.jpg',
        'http://www.themoralofthestoryis.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/test.gif'
    ];


$('#logo').mouseover( changeImage );

function changeImage() {
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
    var image = images[ rand ];
    if ( image == $('#logo').attr('src') ) {
        changeImage();
        return false;
    }

    $('#logo').attr('src', image);
};
```

Comment: I think that jquery is not needed in this situation. It's very basic javascript being used.

Comment: the use of jquery isn't the emphasis. it's the cleaning up. Using images instead of p, replacing the incorrectly placed commas with semi-colons etc.